# How to hide a div if cookie exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, onclick

Looking to generate a cookie on a click of a button, then for it to check if the cookie exists, if the cookie exists then hide div.

Here is where I am at with my code, but I cannot seem to get the if statement to function as intended..

```js
    (function ($) {
      
      $(".cookieSetter").click(function () {
         $.cookie('cookieMade', 'jobDone');
      });
      
      if ($.cookie('cookieMade', 'jobDone') == "true") {
        $('.box').hide();
      }
        
    })(jQuery);
```

```css
    button {
      height: 48px;
      width: 112px;
      background: #fff;
      border: 2px solid #2d2d2d;
      color: #2d2d2d;
      font-size: 14px;
      font-weight: 600;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .blue {
      background: blue;
    }
    
    .box {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      margin-top: 10px;
    }
```

```html
    <a class="cookieSetter" href="#"><button>Set cookie</button></a>
    <div class="blue box"></div>
```

Comment: you want to hide the div onClick? and what is the value of `$.cookie` and where did you get that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your usage of `$.cookie('cookieMade', 'jobDone')` is the setter of the cookie and not the getter. If you want to get the value of the cookie you should use `$.cookie('cookieMade')`, and check the returned value:

```
if ($.cookie('cookieMade') == 'jobDone') {
    // Do something if the cookie's value is 'jobDone'
}
```

In your case:

```
if ($.cookie('cookieMade') == 'jobDone') {
    // Do something if the cookie's value is 'jobDone'
    $('.box').hide();
}
```

### update

The problem with codepen is that each time you reload the page you get a different `path`, and by default, `$.cookie` sets the path of the cookie to the current path.
You can set the `path` to `/` so the cookie will be valid for all of the pages in your domain:

```
$.cookie('cookieMade', 'jobDone', {path: '/'});
```

This will work in codepen (and should also work in your website).

Comment: I have adjusted the codepen code now to reflect the above mentioned, and it is definitely adding the cookie correctly, but not hiding the box?

Comment: sorry, I forgot the link http://codepen.io/Tekkie/pen/JRrwdg thank you.

Comment: it worked perfectly thank you for your help it is very much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax for checking the cookie isn't correct. You need to use the 'getter' for the value. Also note that you can use `toggle()` to show/hide the element as needed. Try this:

```
(function($) {
    $(".cookieSetter").click(function () {
        $.cookie('cookieMade', 'jobDone');
    });

    $('.box').toggle($.cookie('cookieMade') != 'jobDone');
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: that works for me - pleople my need to add jquery.cookie.js plugin to make it work

Comment: That's true. I didn't mention it in the answer as the question already includes it.

Answer (score 0):

```
When you set the cookie you can raise event and subscribe that event wherever is
needed.
(function ($) {  
  $(".cookieSetter").click(function () {
     $.cookie('cookieMade', 'jobDone');
    $(document).triggerHandler('_cookieSetter', true);
  });  
  $(document).off('_cookieSetter.add').on('_cookieSetter.add', function () {
               if ($.cookie('cookieMade') == 'jobDone') {
    $('.box').hide();
}});
})(jQuery);
```